# Eclipse Project Explorer - Where is project list stored?

Tags: eclipse

How does Eclipse populate the Project Explorer?  Where on the filesystem is the list of current projects stored and in what format?

If I move a project directory `Bar/Foo` from some workbench `Bar/` to some other workbench `Baz/`, and then open `Baz/` as current workbench, project `Foo` does not show up.  Clearly Eclipse is not using existance of directories in the workbench directory to find projects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Projects are declared in the workspace. You have to import or create the project to have them exist. Their existence is stored in some area in the .metadata folder in the workspace.

If you want to get the list of projects through the API, you will need the Resources API.

To get the list specifically, this is the call:

```
    IProject projects[] = ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace().getRoot()
            .getProjects();
```

Answer (score 1):

As Francis Upton said, the list of projects is stored in the .metadata folder, most likely in the .metadata/plugins/org.eclipse.core.resources folder.

You can modify this list programmatically using the Resources API as shown by Francis, or if you want to import an existing project (as stated in the question), use the Import existing project... wizard from File/Import... in the General category.